# Reading from a file is causing serialVersionUID errors

Tags: java, serialization

I've been searching the internet (including stackoverflow) for an explanation of this error that I'm getting, but haven't come across an answer (or at least one I can understand).

I'm trying to serialize a class so I can save the object to a file.  The first step is to read the current contents of the file so I can add a new object in.  For that I use this code:

```
//masterFilePath is a java.io.File that contains the "master file" I'm reading.
//ReportList is a simple extension of ArrayList

String[][] returner = null; 
ReportList listOfReports = null;

try{
    FileInputStream fileReader = new FileInputStream(masterFilePath);
    ObjectInputStream objectReader = new ObjectInputStream(fileReader);
    listOfReports = (ReportList) (objectReader.readObject()); //Problem Line
    objectReader.close();

} catch (IOException | ClassNotFoundException e){
    e.printStackTrace();
}
```

When it gets to the line marked `//Problem Line` it throws this error:

```
com.Private.automatorContainers.ReportList; local class incompatible: stream classdesc serialVersionUID = 1, local class serialVersionUID = 8996775622132817386
```

I know that the `8996...` is the  `serialVersionUID` I currently have in `ReportList` what I can't figure out is where the 1 comes from.

My working theory is this:  Before I implemented `Serializable` in ReportList I had a UID that equaled `1L`, so I assume that's where the 1 comes from (right?  Please confirm or deny?)

I have two questions.  Firstly, where is the UID stored? I didn't know anything like that was stored outside of a .java file?   I figured everything else was done at compile time.  Clearly there is a hole in my understanding.

Secondly, how do I get my program to realize that the 1 is the wrong `serialVersionUID` and it needs to be updated?

Comment: The `ReportList` class definition should have the same `serialVersionUID` while serializing and de-serializing . The code which had serialized the class to file must have `serialVersionUID` defined as 1, where as the class file currently used has defined it as `8996775622132817386`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The fundamental problem here is that the content of that file on the filesystem was written using a version of `ReportList` that's incompatible with the version being used by your running code. Java detects this incompatibility by recording the serialVersionUID of the object's class when writing it to a stream; later on, when you read that object back from the stream, Java compares the recorded serialVersionUID against the serialVersionUID that it finds at runtime for the object's class.

Your options are to either:

- Re-create that content using the latest version of your running code, using whatever process you originally used to generate it.
- Modify your running code so that it's compatible with the version that wrote the file originally, by setting the `serialVersionUID` of the `ReportList` class in your running code to `1L` to match what's in the file, as others in this thread have suggested. Note that you can only do this if you're *sure* the fields in the object from the file are the same as what's in your latest code, or you've overridden the default object serialization behavior.

Comment: And, for the record, I went with option one, which worked perfectly.

Answer (score 0):

If the stream states that the serialized object has `serialVersionUID = 1`, the only way to read it is to set your class serialVersionUID also to 1.

```
private static final long serialVersionUID = 1L;
```

If you do not define a `serialVersionUID` java will generate one for you based on the properties of your class, and this will most likely not be 1.

When you wrote the object to file it seems the serialVersionUid was 1 within the class definition.

Change the definition to 1, recompile the JAR and it should function.